# Unable to import a csv into a table in SQLite: no such table error

Tags: sql, csv, sqlite

I have a wireshark dump in .csv format that I want to analyze. I tried importing the CSV file as described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles). These are the commands I ran from the command line-

```
sqlite> create table network(no,time,source,dest,proto,info);
sqlite> .separator ",";
sqlite> .import E:\\Pavan\\_DataScience\\MP1\\network_data1\\challenge_network\\TestNetworkData.csv network;
Error: no such table: network;
sqlite> .tables
network
sqlite>
```

The `.table` command clearly shows that the `network` table is indeed present. I am not getting why the import command fails.

**PS**: I am running the sqlite3 executable downloaded from the [official site](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) on Windows.

Comment: remove the semicolon at the end of `.import` line and try again

Comment: @Griddoor Thanks a ton. That was the problem. Am pretty new to SQL, so couldnt get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite, you need semicolons at the end of all of your SQL statements. Without them, it will give you a continuation prompt and wait for you to enter more text to be added to the current SQL command. After it receives the semicolon, it will pass the statement on to the SQLite library for execution.

However, if the line begins with a dot (.), then the sqlite3 program interprets that line itself without sending it to the SQLite library. Dot statements do not need semicolons. Just remove the semicolon from the .import line. (One clue that that's the problem is that the semicolon appears in the table name in the error message.)

I'm surprised your .separator line worked with the semicolon at the end. It definitely would've worked without it.

;